# what cause the header function not redirecting on my login page?

Tags: php

please can anyone find and improve in my code that where i am missing  when i am trying to redirect on my login page `https://localhost/sms/login.php`  when the session is not set but page getting error like below showing the screenshot 
[image]

and my code below what i am trying to achieve please check

```
<?php
session_start();
$ulr='';
$adminurl=ROOTdir.'admin/adminDash.php';
$loginurl=ROOTdir.'login.php';
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !isset($_SERVER['HTTP'])){
    //echo "both are null";
    $ulr="https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}else if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || empty($_SERVER['HTTP']) ){
    $ulr="https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

if(isset($_SESSION['uid']) && $ulr == "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/sms/' ){

        if(isset($adminurl)){
                header("location:".$adminurl);
                echo "ddsa";
        }
    }else if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
        header("location:".$adminurl);
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
        if(isset($loginurl)){
            //echo $loginurl;

            header("Location:https://localhost/sms/login.php");
        }
         // echo "session is not setsss";
         // header("location:".$adminurl);
     }
?>
```

your any participation would be very helpful.

after deleting that above code and i rewrite again to session not set but the same problem occuring like previous as after redirecting on `https://localhost/sms/login.php` the login page not opening and getting error like 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U05rQ.png)

**updated is here below**
`code of session.php`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9l5g.png)

`code of session.php`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZbPK.png)

`code of adminDash.php`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sn0Z.png)

i want when we go on link like `https://localhost/sms/admin/adminDash.php` if there the session is to be not set then after it will redirect to `https://localhost/sms/login.php`

Comment: since the `if (!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){` is not set so it will always be looping ...

Comment: if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/sms/login.php'){
}

Comment: Nothing happening I tried that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it say too many redirect, probably you are into a loop.